# How do I fix this error when creating a candy machine with metaplex?

Tags: visual-studio-code, solana, unhandled-promise-rejection, metaplex

I am following this tutorial "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LLx7SMAOag&t=446s" and at 9:28 he tells us to input this

```
ts-node js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-cli.ts upload ./assets --env devnet --keypair ~/config/solana/devnet-test.json
```

His result is an initialized candy machine as shown in the video. Mine is the following:

```
Beginning the upload for 150 (png+json) pairs
started at: 1634300753134
wallet public key: GLCNNSs9QA1YqxkY6Ptq3pb6UZrkRbwGw7ZUGeJK1CCg
(node:6434) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: failed to get info about          
account 63N3bBDCVVzdCaofQAnY5s4kcZodw1evomptDgNQ4feK: FetchError: request to https://api.devnet.solana.com/ failed, reason: connect ENETUNREACH 128.0.113.156:443
at Connection.getAccountInfo (/Users/hectorbardales/Desktop/metaplex/js/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:2404:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async Function.fetchIdl    
(/Users/hectorbardales/Desktop/metaplex/js/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/index.ts:309:25)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:6434) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6434) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

What do I do to fix this? (I'm running this in visual studio code on a Mac)

Comment: please check followings
1. Please check creator address in each metadata.
It should be valid public key on solana network.
2. Please check solana cli is working on your terminal.
ex: solana balance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did for example

```sh
ts-node ./js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload \
    -e devnet \
    -k ./js/cm.devnet.json \
    -cp ./js/config.json \
    -c temp \
    ./js/assets-pictures
```

I made sure the path was clear and direct to each file, make sure for `-k` its path is to the file created when you did your keygen.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't, perhaps try airdropping 10 SOLs into that wallet address listed above? But do 5 first, then 5 again.

I can't remember what error I got, but I did have issues with that line.

Command for airdropping Sol is simple. Solana Airdrop x (x is your SOL amount).

Idk, worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve this by changing to a different internet connection. The original connection was working completely fine but for some reason, I have never been able to use upload/create_candy_machine commands with it.

Answer (score 0):

ENETUNREACH is a connection-related error. Even if you are able to browse the web or do other things, the best option is to test again with a new internet connection.